# JsonIgnore value skipped in Mixin if JsonProperty is present in parent class

Tags: java, jackson

I've a User Object that can't be modified  which looks like this:

```
@Value
@Builder
@ToString(exclude = {"id"})
public class User {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    String id;

    @JsonProperty("testing")
    String testing;
}
```

I want to avoid the field id from ever being logged. While ToString excludes takes care when I use the toString method this doesn't work if I use objectMapper.

To ensure that I take care of objectMapper, I created a UserMixin:

```
public interface UserMixin {
    @JsonIgnore
    String getId();
}
```

and then registered it to my objectMapper this way:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.addMixIn(User.class, UserMixin.class);
```

However if I create a User object and serialize it using objectMapper the JsonIgnore field is skipped and the id field is logged. If I remove @JsonProperty from the parent class it works. However I can't modify that, so what are my options?